# Get the number of integers between each given range - without external packages

Tags: python, arrays, range, binary-search

The task:

> Write a function that receives 3 lists and returns an array. The first list contains n integers, their values range between 0 and 10^9. "numbers".
>
> The second list is a low-range list, which contains the lower end of a range, it contains q integers. "low".
>
> The third list is a high-range list, which contains the higher end of a range, it contains q integers. "high".
>
> The function should return a list that contains the number of integers in the first list, that fall in its range, given by the low-range and high-range lists.
>
> In the returned list, at index i, there should be the number of integers in "numbers" which are bigger or equal to low[i] and smaller or equal to high[i].
>
>  **You can only import math, no other imports are allowed**
>
>  the list may not be sorted

Examples:
count_range([12,13,14,15,17],[14],[14]) should return [1] 
count_range([12,13,14,15,17],[14,15],[14,18]) should return [1,2] 
count_range([12,13,14,15,17],[12],[17]) should return [5]

This is my solution but it's not efficient enough, I need ways to optimize it or solve it differently without having to import any external packages.

```
def binarySearch(data, val):
    highIndex = len(data) - 1
    lowIndex = 0
    while highIndex > lowIndex:
        index = math.ceil((highIndex + lowIndex) / 2)
        sub = data[index]
        if sub > val:
            if highIndex == index:
                return sorted([highIndex, lowIndex])
            highIndex = index
        else:
            if lowIndex == index:
                return sorted([highIndex, lowIndex])
            lowIndex = index
    return sorted([highIndex, lowIndex])


def count_range(numbers, low, high):
    numbers.sort()
    result = []
    low_range_dict = {}
    high_range_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] not in low_range_dict:
            low_range_dict[numbers[i]] = i
        high_range_dict[numbers[i]] = i
    for i in range(len(low)):
        low_r = low[i]
        high_r = high[i]
        if low_r not in low_range_dict:
            low_range_dict[low_r] = binarySearch(numbers, low_r)[0]
            high_range_dict[low_r] = low_range_dict[low_r]
        low_index = low_range_dict.get(low_r)
        if high_r not in high_range_dict:
            high_range_dict[high_r] = binarySearch(numbers, high_r)[0]
            low_range_dict[high_r] = high_range_dict[high_r]
        high_index = high_range_dict.get(high_r)
        if low_r in numbers or low_r < numbers[0]:
            low_index -= 1
        result.append(high_index - low_index)
    return result
```

Comment: The question is weirdly written. Python does not have builtin arrays, only lists. Arrays exist in the standard library, or in numpy. Also the examples have the first array sorted, but the text doesn't say whether that's always the case.

Comment: @HåkenLid sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant lists I'll edit the post, and it doesn't have to be sorted, the examples are just by chance sorted

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not efficient enough"? Does it give the correct result? The examples inputs are very short lists, so that there will be very little difference in efficiency between algorithms. What are typical data sizes for "numbers", "low" and "high" that you would use when this solution is "not efficient enough"?

Comment: @HåkenLid it was tested on 100,000 numbers and 1000 ranges, it runs correctly but takes at least two seconds.

Comment: @HåkenLid Instructors have an unfortunate tendency to use the word *array* when they actually intend their charges to use a list, because an array is the nearest equivalent basic data structure in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we could use any module from the standard library, we could do write a very simple solution.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from functools import lru_cache, partial

def count_range(numbers, lows, highs):
    index = lru_cache()(partial(bisect_left, sorted(numbers)))
    return [index(hi + 1) - index(lo) for (lo, hi) in zip(lows, highs)]
```

But we can write our own (simplified) equivalent of `partial`, `lru_cache` and `bisect_left`, so the imports are not needed.

It is less complicated than your original code, and should probably run faster, but I don't know how big the difference is.

We'll use a simpler bisect function for the binary search. And we don't need two different memoization dictionaries for high and low range.

```
# This bisect is based on the reference implementation in the standard library.
# in cpython this is actually implemented in C, and is faster.
def bisect_left(a, x):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted."""
    lo, hi = 0, len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if a[mid] < x:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid
    return lo


def count_range(numbers, lows, highs):
    numbers.sort()
    # instead of both low_range_dict and high_range_dict
    # we only need a single memoization dictionary. 
    # We could also use @functools.cache from the standard library
    memo = {}
    def index(val):
        """Memoized bisect"""
        if not val in memo:
            memo[val] = bisect_left(numbers, val)
        return memo[val]

    return [index(hi + 1) - index(lo) for (lo, hi) in zip(lows, highs)]
```